# Can I create a bookmarklet button with icon?

Tags: javascript, mozilla

Can I create a bookmarklet button with icon?

Comment: Your screenshot isn't working.

Comment: I know its old ... You can add symbols, like ♥. Also You can [create button from bookmarklet](http://superuser.com/questions/65564/how-to-add-firefox-bookmark-as-toolbar-button) if that helps You somehow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not automatically; see [SO #521040](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/521040/how-to-have-favicon-icon-set-when-bookmarklet-dragged-to-toolbar)

Users can set favicons after adding in Firefox using Stylish or Favicon Picker, but it doesn't seem to be possible to enclose one in the bookmarklet.  This makes sense since the code is running from your browser, not from any web host, and so there is no domain for the code to reference the icon from.

Comment: so how the bokkmarklet in the screen shot is showing an icon, is it something special because they are from Mozilla?

Comment: Sorry, I can't get that screenshot image to display, it just gives me the URL again - it may be stored behind a login page.