# Assigning a Bookmarklet Icon

Tags: bookmarklet

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to have favicon / icon set when bookmarklet dragged to toolbar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/521040/how-to-have-favicon-icon-set-when-bookmarklet-dragged-to-toolbar)

I created a bookmarklet on the following page...

http://www.wishwrapped.com/pinit

Can anyone tell me how to set the icon when it is dragged to the bookmark bar? Right now it doesn't display one at all. Shouldn't it at least pick up the favicon I have for the site?

thanks

Comment: Dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5952387/adding-favicon-to-javascript-bookmarklet-uses-window-open , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/521040/how-to-have-favicon-icon-set-when-bookmarklet-dragged-to-toolbar

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: No

I have tried to find a solution to this issue several times before. My firm conclusion is that the bookmarklet creator can NOT directly set an icon for a bookmarklet.

Long answer: Think of it this way... A bookmarklet is a type of bookmark. A bookmark's icon is set by web page it points to. In fact it can update later if the user visits that page and the icon has been updated.

A bookmarklet does not point to any web page. So the browser has no meaninful way to choose the icon. It could use the icon from the page it was distributed on, but even that doesn't really make sense, because a bookmarklet can be distributed on any web page.

There have been possible ways that a user can try to set an icon by following some steps, but that only worked in some browsers, not all, and is probably outdated and useless by now.

There is probably some way a user could set the icon using some kind addon.

Also, the bookmarklet creator could provide an add-on or extension which does the same thing as the bookmarklet ( http://www.google.com/search?q=convert+bookmarklet+to+add-on ).